# No certificate is generated in .hfc-key-store

Tags: node.js

I'm using an AWS Ubuntu 16.04 LTS following Hyperledger Fabric readthedocs tutorial. I followed steps in "Writing Your First Applications". When I ran "node enrollAdmin.js", a eCert and key material is expected to be generated in a hfc-key-store directory, but nothing is generated in this folder, which means the folder is still empty after running the command. I looked into the code in this js file, in lines 54-55, only two arguments are provided, but from the API from this link:https://jimthematrix.github.io/FabricCAClient.html#enroll__anchor, the fabric_ca_client.enroll function should receive three arguments, which means the third argument 'csr' is not given in the js file. Strangely, no error information is shown after running the command, and the only information i got from the terminal is "store path: $mypath/hfc-key-store".

Any one knows what the problem occurs?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After I switch node version from 6.12.0 to 6.9.5, this issue is resolved. Looks like the node version has to be 6.9.x